# Time-Series data viewer

Tags: tool-request, time-series, visualization

Looking for a way of visualizing public power generation data. Typical data set has 1–5 years of hourly data, and anything up to 30 columns. Needing to pan and zoom, and perhaps select sections. Needs to run on Linux.

The sometimes recommended [TimeSearcher 2](https://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/timesearcher/) is very shaky under Mono, and has unusual data format requirements.

**EDIT**: I'm looking to compare years of hourly generation data against regional demand. Some of the data streams may not have corresponding frequencies. I'm not looking for much programming input, as most of the analysis will be visual, so zooming and panning are important. There's unlikely to be a pre-made importer for the XML format used by the particular ISO, so I'd likely be spending the programming time on that. Not sure if I need any stats capabilities, though rolling daily/weekly averages/minima/maxima could be helpful.

I'm potentially going up against a very polished but misguided speaker in a few days who is using an entrenched industry position to ensure that expensive, polluting energy remains the status quo.

Comment: If you could add more information, that would help narrow down the answers. For example: Are you only looking for desktop applications, or are web-based solutions fine? How much programming should be involved? Is your focus exploration or presentation?

Comment: @scruss, what did you end up using?

Comment: None, yet. Disappeared down a bit of an R rabbit hole. It looks like it could handle and graph the data (after a lot of cleanup) but it's a steep learning curve if you've never used it before.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to suggest a good tool without knowing how deep into programming you want to go, or if the tool is for exploration or presentation.

But here is a sample of many good tools out there:

**Javascript:**

- [Envision.js](http://www.humblesoftware.com/envision/demos/timeseries)
- [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/)
- [Cubism](http://square.github.io/cubism/)

**R:**

- [Dygraphs](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/)
- [Google Charts](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/google-charts.html)

**Python:**

- [Matplotlib](http://blog.mafr.de/2012/03/11/time-series-data-with-matplotlib/)
- [Pandas](http://earthpy.org/pandas-basics.html) (using Matplotlib)
- [Plotly blog](http://blog.plot.ly/post/117105992082/time-series-graphs-eleven-stunning-ways-you-can) - Time Series Graphs & Eleven Stunning Ways You Can Use Them

**Tableau**

- If you don't mind that the data is shared, you can use [Tableau Public](https://public.tableau.com/s/) for free
- [Alternatives to Tableau Public](http://butleranalytics.com/5-alternatives-to-tableau-public/)

Comment: Thanks - [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) looks great. I was kind of looking for a pre-rolled tool, as I've already had to do a lot of fighting with the data just to get it in a place to analyse. It's Generation [Output and Capability](http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputCapability/PUB_GenOutputCapability_20150421.xml#) Data from Ontario.

Comment: For exploration and hooking up with data sets, Tableau (Public) is pretty good, but doesn't work on Linux as far as I know.